# Extracting for value to use on label element?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, label, html-helper

**Hi,**

Label has a for attribute that pointe to the editor for example :

```
<label for="ModelViewAd_Title">Titel</label>
```

I am building a custom helper for generating the label and this methodhead look like this :

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, Boolean showToolTip)
```

What is the easiest way to extract this for value? Or do I have to manually build the for value?

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article solved my problem :

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/03/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes.aspx

In detail :

```
string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
    Boolean showToolTip
)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
    var id = self.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(metadata.PropertyName);
    // do something with the id
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will only get me the last part for example Title instead of ModelViewAd_Title?

Comment: Are you using EditorTemplates?

Comment: I am using html helpers like html.TextBoxFor but not html.EditorFor